# Recursively parse/convert structured text to dictionary

Tags: python, regex

Is there any good regex/function or packages that allows us to parse indented structured text/data into a dictionary? For example, I have data something like this (can have deeper levels than I mentioned below):

```
xyz1                      : 14
xyz2                      : 35
xyz3                      : 14
xyz4
  sub1_xyz4
    sub1_sub1_xyz4        : 45
    sub2_sub1_xyz4        : b1fawe
  sub2 xyz4               : 455
xyz5                      : 2424
```

And I want to convert it into a dictionary like:

```
{
    'xyz1': '14',
    'xyz2': '34',
    'xyz3': '14',
    'xyz4': {
        'sub1_xyz4': {
            'sub1_sub1_xyz4': '45',
            'sub2_sub1_xyz4': 'b1fawe',
        },
        'sub2_xyz4': '455'
    },
    'xyz5': '2424'
}
```

I tried the following but not able to get it consistently. I feel like there is a very good recursive (so that it can handle unknown depths) function when trying to manage the indented/sub attributes. Any suggestions?

```
def parse_output(value, indent=0):
    parsed_dict = dict()
    if indent > 0:
       for i in re.split('\n(?!\s{,%d})' % (indent - 1), value):
            print("split value is: : ", i)
            if '\n' not in i:
                iter_val = iter(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split(' : ', i))))
                parsed_dict = {**parsed_dict, **dict(zip(iter_val, iter_val))}
            else:
                parse_bearer_info(re.split('\n', i, 1)[1])
                iter_val = iter(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split('\n', i, 1))))
                parsed_dict = {**parsed_dict, **dict(zip(iter_val, iter_val))}
    else:
        for i in re.split('\n(?!\s+)', value):
            #print("iteration value is: ", i)
            if '\n' not in i:
                iter_val = iter(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split(' : ', i))))
                parsed_dict = {**parsed_dict, **dict(zip(iter_val, iter_val))}
            else:
                #print(re.split('\n', i, 1))
                #out = parse_bearer_info(re.split('\n', i, 1)[1], 4)
                iter_val = iter(list(map(lambda x: x.strip(), re.split('\n', i, 1))))
                parsed_dict = {**parsed_dict, **dict(zip(iter_val, iter_val))}

    return parsed_dict
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.groupby` with recursion:

```
import itertools, re, json
_data = [re.split('\s+:\s+', i) for i in filter(None, content.split('\n'))]
def group_data(d):
  _d = [[a, list(b)] for a, b in itertools.groupby(d, key=lambda x:bool(x[-1]) and not x[0].startswith(' '))]
  _new_result = {}
  for a, b in _d:
    if a:
      _new_result.update(dict([[c, _d] for c, [_d] in b]))
    else:
      _new_result[b[0][0]] = group_data([[c[2:], _d] for c, _d in b[1:]])
  return _new_result

print(json.dumps(group_data([[a, b] for a, *b in _data]), indent=4))
```

Output:

```
{
 "xyz1": "14",
 "xyz2": "35",
 "xyz3": "14",
 "xyz4": {
    "sub1_xyz4": {
        "sub1_sub1_xyz4": "45",
        "sub2_sub1_xyz4": "b1fawe"
      },
      "sub2 xyz4": "455"
   },
  "xyz5": "2424"
}
```

Where `content` is:

```
xyz1                      : 14
xyz2                      : 35
xyz3                      : 14
xyz4
  sub1_xyz4
    sub1_sub1_xyz4        : 45
    sub2_sub1_xyz4        : b1fawe
  sub2 xyz4               : 455
xyz5                      : 2424
```

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do this recursively, but since you only need to track a single indent level, you could just keep a stack with the current object. Add keys to the last item in the stack. When the value is empty, add a new dictionary and push it to the stack. When the indent decreases, pop from the stack.

Something like:

```
res = {}
stack = [res]
cur_indent = 0
for line in s.split('\n'):
    indent = len(line) - len(line.lstrip())
    if (indent < cur_indent):               # backing out
        stack.pop()
        cur_indent = indent
    else:
        cur_indent = indent

    vals = line.replace(" ", "").split(':')

    current_dict = stack[-1]
    if(len(vals) == 2):                    
        current_dict[vals[0]] = vals[1]
    else:                                   # no value, must be a new level
        current_dict[vals[0]] = {}
        stack.append(current_dict[vals[0]])
```

Result:

```
{'xyz1': '14',
 'xyz2': '35',
 'xyz3': '14',
 'xyz4': {'sub1_xyz4': {'sub1_sub1_xyz4': '45', 'sub2_sub1_xyz4': 'b1fawe'},
          'sub2xyz4': '455'},
 'xyz5': '2424'}
```

Comment: Thanks, this works but I suppose I didn't mention this in my description but the indent levels can go further than what I have mentioned in description.  Still very nice.  I'd use the indent level to track the current and future ones.